# Empty string should be 'false'

Tags: javascript, if-statement, conditional-statements

Javascript code:

```js
var empty = '';
console.warn(typeof(empty && null)); // 'string'
```

Why does the statement "empty && null" return the empty string? Expected result: false.

Comment: `empty` is just the name of the variable. So, `typeof` returns the type of the variable named `empty` and it's `string`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is clearly stated in the [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators), regarding the `&&` (Logical and operator):

> Returns expr1 if it can be converted to false; otherwise, returns expr2. Thus, when used with Boolean values, && returns true if both operands are true; otherwise, returns false.

So indeed, it will return the first expression in your case - the empty string, by design. In the context of an **if**, where the statement is interpreted as `boolean`, then you get a True/False result like you expect, or if you do the cast directly.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, your code evaluates to this:

If empty is "truthy" run `typeof` on `null`, else run it on the `empty` variable.
So `empty` is falsy because it's an empty string, that's why it runs `typeof` on it and not on `null`. `string` is the `typeof` the string `""`.